# Javascript getting Cookie won't do on certain value

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this function in my PHP :

```
setcookie("UserPusser", $user, time() + 604800, "/pusser/beta/");
setcookie("PassPusser", $pass, time() + 604800, "/pusser/beta/");
setcookie("NotifPusser", $notif, time() + 604800, "/pusser/beta/");
```

And I have this function in my javascript

```
function getThisCookie(name){
    var value;
    var singleCookie = document.cookie.split(";")
    for(var x in singleCookie){
        var y = singleCookie[x].split("=");
        if(y[0] == name) {
            value = y[1];
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

When I type `alert(getThisCookie('UserPusser'))` the result is what I want. But when I tried to write `alert(getThisCookie('NotifPusser'));` or `alert(getThisCookie('PassPusser'));` the result is : undefined.

Anyone can help me?

What I'm trying to do is make the browser remember the value of checkbox each time the page reload.

Comment: What is the value of `$notif` before invoking the php code? What is the cookie value before invoking the JavaScript code?

Comment: did you debug the getThisCookie function? are you sure the if(y[0]==name) is ever true for the third cookie?

Comment: at first, I'm trying to manually set that `$notif = 'true'` So, before invoking the php code the `$notif` doesn't exist.

But, when I invoke the database, and check the cookie in the browser. It is there, with the value that I want.

Perroloco : No, It never reachs the 3rd Cookie, regardless the cookie name. But wait, I'll try to exchange the cookie position.

Comment: Perroloco : You were right. It is even worser that I think. Javascript only get the value that I want on the FIRST Cookie only. In other words, UserPusser is OK, PassPusser is undefined, NotifPusser is undefined. 
I don't know what cause this. Anyone?

-- SORRY -- 
My above post, it is not 'database', it is 'page'

Comment: This is due to the fact, that the cookie values are not separated by `;` only, but by `; ` (semicolon + whitespace). Just modify your code to `singleCookie[x].split('; ')` and you should be able to retrieve the desired values.

Comment: I did a workaround about this. I tried to get the cookie using PHP Function and it works. Maybe the cookie that defined in PHP is not very compatible with Javascript. It is just my deduction. 

Thanks all, especially you, Perroloco.

Comment: @Tharabas Magnificently it is working! Thanks! But, How did the cookie ended having whitespace?

Comment: Just use a better cookie script like [this one](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just for completeness a full answer here instead of only the hint within the comments:*

Cookie values are separated by `;` (semicolon + whitespace)
This leaves you with something like this:

```
cookie = 'a=123; b=456; c=678'
```

In order to separate them you have to split them by the same delimiter.
With modern browsers (JS 1.6+ I guess, not quite sure right now) or libraries like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) you could as well put them into an object.

```
// if your browser supports 'reduce'
var cookieObject = document.cookie.split('; ').reduce(function(o, kvp) {
  var split_kvp = kvp.split('=');
  o[split_kvp[0]] = split_kvp[1];
  return o;
}, {});

// underscore.js version
var cookieObject = _.reduce(document.cookie.split('; '), function(o, kvp) {
  var split_kvp = kvp.split('=');
  o[split_kvp[0]] = split_kvp[1];
  return o;
}, {});
```

Anyway after performing any of those you can easily access the values you are looking for:

```
cookieObject.a == 123
cookieObject.b == 456
```

Just remember that those are *readOnly*. In order to modify them you'd have to write the object back to the `document.cookie`

```
// again, modern browser version
document.cookie = Object.keys(cookieObject).map(function(key) {
  return key + '=' + cookieObject[key];
}).join('; ');

// with underscore.js
document.cookie = _.chain(cookieObject).keys().map(function(key) {
  return key + '=' + cookieObject[key];
}).value().join('; ')
```